# Generics in Java

Tags: java, generics

I came across something peculiar today. Take a look at this code snippet:

```
List <Rectangle> test1 = new LinkedList<Rectangle>();
List <Shape> test2 = test1; //Compiler Error;
```

This is of course is assuming that class Rectangle is a subclass of Shape.
Can someone explain to me why this is an error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this code worked, you could continue by inserting into `test2` a `Circle` -- thus utterly breaking the guarantee that `test1` makes, that only `Rectangle`s will ever be inserted in it.

The general principle (language independent -- a matter of logic -- even though counter-intuitive): a bag of bananas is NOT a bag of fruit... in a world of mutable objects (the functional programming world, where every object is immutable once created, is **MUCH** simpler!).  That's because you can add an apple to a bag of fruit (since an apple is a piece of fruit), but you can't add an apple to a bag of bananas (since an apple is not a banana).

BTW, this is very similar to the reason a square is not a rectangle (again, in a world of mutable objects): because given a (mutable) rectangle you can mutate the two sides independently, but, given a square, you can't.  (In geometry, a square IS indeed a rectangle - but that's because, in geometry like in functional programming, there is no concept of "mutating" an object!-).

Answer (score 5):

You need to use wild card. Like this:

```
List<Rectangle> test1 = new LinkedList<Rectangle>();
List<? extends Shape> test2 = test1;
```

As `Rectangle` extends `Shape`.

The reason for this is that if test2 is just `List<Shape>`, you will expect test2.add(..) to accept any shape but that is not the case if you allows test1 (which is `List<Rectangle>`), test1 will not accept any shape that is not `Rectangle`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

This is a common source of confusion - generics are not covariant in Java.

For a really good explanation of this please see [Java theory and practice: Generics gotchas](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp01255.html):

> While you might find it helpful to
>   think of collections as being an
>   abstraction of arrays, they have some
>   special properties that collections do
>   not. Arrays in the Java language are
>   covariant -- which means that if
>   Integer extends Number (which it
>   does), then not only is an Integer
>   also a Number, but an Integer[] is
>   also a Number[], and you are free to
>   pass or assign an Integer[] where a
>   Number[] is called for. (More
>   formally, if Number is a supertype of
>   Integer, then Number[] is a supertype
>   of Integer[].) You might think the
>   same is true of generic types as well
>   -- that List is a supertype of List, and that you can pass a
>   List where a List is
>   expected. Unfortunately, it doesn't
>   work that way.

Answer (score 0):

List<`Shape`> has nothing to do with List<`Rectangle`>. When you are using an array, Shape[] is actually supertype of Rectangle[], because arrays are covariant. But Collections such as List are not covariant. In fact at run time, they will both be erased as List<`Object`>, and when you call any methods from any instances of List<`Shape`>, List<`Rectangle`>, the VM will call the methods of List<`Object`> but with some other code inserted to check the type safety.