# Why can't I call a method with a list of enum which implement an interface?

Tags: java, generics, enums

I am trying to call a method which takes a list of Interface with a list of Enum (which implements Interface). This gives the following compile error:

```
The method method(List<Interface>) in the type Class is not applicable for the arguments (List<Enum>)
```

This is the interface:

```
public interface Interface {
}
```

This is the enum that implements the interface:

```
public enum Enum implements Interface {
}
```

This is the calling class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Class {
    public static void method(List<Interface> list){
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List <Enum> enumList = new ArrayList<Enum>();
        method(enumList); //This line gives the compile error.
    }
}
```

Why is there a compile error? To me it seems that it should work because the Enum implements that interface.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generics in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1794842/generics-in-java)

Comment: Yes, that is a duplicate. I couldn't find that one when I was looking earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because even is `Car` extends `Vehicle`, `List<Car>` does **not** extend `List<Vehicle>`. If it did, you could do the following:

```
List<Car> listOfCars = new ArrayList<Car>();
List<Vehicle> listOfVehicles = listOfCars;
listOfVehicles.add(new Bicycle());
// and now the list of cars contains a bicycle: not pretty.
```

Comment: Note that you *can* do the same thing with arrays (results in an ArrayStoreException), and that cannot be fixed to preserve compatibility.

Answer (score 5):

```
public static void method(List<? extends Interface> list){
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `List<Enum>` is-not-a `List<Interface>`.

You should either change the variable to `List<Interface>`, or change the method signature to take `List<? extends Interface>`

Answer (score 1):

Though the Enum implements the Interface, List< Enum >  is not subtype of List < Interface >.
If you modify the method signature to following will work.

```
method(List<? extends Interface> list)
```

For further details go through the documentation
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html