# Java generic parameters and inheritance

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, polymorphism

supposed we know that ViewGroup extends View. 
Further we have a generic, parametrized `class A<T extends View>`

**Question:**
 Why wont method `C.add()` accept `new A<ViewGroup>()` as parameter? 
Shouldn't it work, because of polymorphism?

[image: Class diagram]

**SOLUTION:**
Singning add with `? extends View` lets add accept `new A<ViewGroup>()` as a parameter.

[image: Solution]

Comment: Though I didn't get what exactly you want to say, this link might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909995/why-cant-i-call-a-method-with-a-list-of-enum-which-implement-an-interface

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You signed your `add` method as:

```
static void add(A<View>)
```

but you probably meant:

```
static void add(A<? extends View> a)
```

Comment: This still won't work because `new A<ViewGroup>()` is invalid.

Comment: @tskuzzy What do you mean? It's like `new ArrayList<ViewGroup>()`.

Comment: The OP had a typo in the question. He originally said that View extended ViewGroup. :P

Comment: Thnx, signing add with `add(A<? extends View> a)` lets add() accept `new A<ViewGroup>()` thnx. Sorry for my initial typo.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite because `add()` might be using a method of `View` that is not found in `ViewGroup`.

Summary: `View` is a `ViewGroup`, however `ViewGroup` is not a `View`. Polymorphism is where you can assign a `View` object to a `ViewGroup` declaration.

Comment: You said "we know that View extends ViewGroup". o_o

Comment: sorry ... of course ViewGroup extends View, like on the class diagram

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your question isn't very clear because the UML diagram contradicts your text. You say that View extends ViewGroup, but the diagram shows the reverse : ViewGroup extends View.

Now, a `List<Car>` doesn't extend a `List<Vehicle>`. If it were the case, you could do:

```
List<Car> listOfCars = new ArrayList<Car>();
List<Vehicle> listOfVehicles = listOfCars;
listOfVehicles.add(new Bicycle());
// now the list of cars contain a bicycle. Not pretty.
```

Comment: sorry, just edited the sentence, of course `ViewGroup extends View` here.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you said View extends ViewGroup, but the diagram says ViewGroup extends View (which I assume to be right).

Secondly, you are not allowed to pass a `List<ViewGroup>` as a `List<View>`. This is a compile time protection to prevent someone from adding an AnotherView into this list and compromise type-safety of generics.

`List<ViewGroup>` is not a subtype of `List<View>`, but it is a subtype of `List<? extends View>`. So you can modify your method to accept a `List<? extends View>` instead, but be aware that you can't add to the list passed to the method this way.

There is also another syntax called lower bound wildcard (`List<? super ViewGroup>`), as opposed to the upper bound wildcard mentioned above, which enables you to add to the list but you can olny pass in a list of ViewGroup or its parents.

More about wildcards in generics can be found here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html