# Cannot cast from ArrayList<Parcelable> to ArrayList<ClSprite>

Tags: java, casting

In a piece of code I've written, I have this line:

```
         AllSprites = (ArrayList<ClSprite>) savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("AllSprites");
```

I'm getting an error about an invalid cast from an `ArrayList<Parcelable>` to `ArrayList<ClSprite>`.  Why isn't this legal?

Comment: ... Okay, so what's your **question**?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generics in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1794842/generics-in-java)

Comment: Look at the title, Cannot cast from ArrayList<Parcelable> to ArrayList<ClSprite>

Comment: Your ArrayList<ClSprite> should be changed to ArrayList<? extends ClSprite>. Then it will work for subclasses of ClSprite  but you can't add new elements to such arraylist

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is fundamentally unsafe to cast an `ArrayList<Derived>` to an `ArrayList<Base>` or vice-versa.  Doing so opens up a hole in the type system, and Java will throw a `ClassCastException` at runtime if you try this.

The reason is that I could do something like this:

```
ArrayList<Derived> derived = new ArrayList<Derived>();
ArrayList<Base> base = (ArrayList<Derived>) derived; // Not legal!
base.add(new Base()); // Just put a Base into the list, but it only holds Derived!
derived.get(0).doSomethingOnlyInDerived(); // Error!  It's not really a Derived!
```

This is the reason, by the way, that Java's implicit conversions between arrays are broken and why there's `ArrayStoreException`.  This cast isn't safe under all cases.

Answer (score 26):

A simple solution is to set the returning element type like so

`ArrayList<ClSprite> AllSprites = savedInstanceState.<ClSprite>getParcelableArrayList("AllSprites")`

Comment: This is the simplest and brilliant answer to this problem. This should be the accepted answer I guess.

Comment: And it is compatible with javac compiler (used by AndroidStudio). Generic casting i used works in eclipse, but not in Android Studio. Should be accepted answer.

Comment: Actually the type parameter is not needed at the `getParcelableArrayList` method. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17840696/747412) for details.

Comment: Thanks this bug me forever, i love you

Answer (score 17):

Others already explained the problem, but in this case, there is a very simple solution for it. **Simply leave the cast, and your code will compile.** :) :

```
ArrayList<ClSprite> AllSprites = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("AllSprites");
```

Why?

Take a look at the signature of the `getParcelableArrayList` method:

```
public <T extends Parcelable> ArrayList<T> getParcelableArrayList(String key)
```

It's a generic method whose type parameter must be a child of `Parcelable`. If you assign it directly to a variable like this:

```
ArrayList<ClSprite> AllSprites; // declaration somewhere
                                // ClSprite implements Parcelable
...

AllSprites = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("AllSprites");
```

the compiler can deduce the type parameter, so there is no need the cast at all! After deducing, the signature would look like this:

```
public ArrayList<ClSprite> getParcelableArrayList(String key)
```

It is clear the we do not have to cast from `ArrayList<ClSprite>` to `ArrayList<ClSprite>`. :)

But why did you got this error? If you perform a cast and not assign the variable directly to the return value of this method, the compiler cannot deduce the type parameter, it only knows that the returned type is `ArrayList<Parcelable>`. And in this case, the error takes places what the others already explained.

Also if the method would not be generic, but like this:

```
public ArrayList<Parcelable> getParcelableArrayList(String key)
```

you could not assign the return value to `AllSprites`, because there is no type deduction at all, and you cannot convert from `ArrayList<Parcelable>` to `ArrayList<ClSprite>`.
Even though it would make sense, Java uses [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) for generics, and makes these things unsafe at runtime.

Comment: thanks for the great explanation, i tried to set the value for an ArrayList<someParcelableClass> using a ternary operator, which doesn't work. And this answer explains it perfectly.

Comment: Thanks this bug me forever, i love you

Answer (score 5):

That cast is simply illegal in Java; a list-of-parent can't be cast to a list-of-child. Furthermore, the cast to `ArrayList<X>` is dangerous and overly restrictive. You could fix both problems by making the type of `AllSprites` be `List<Parcelable>`.

Comment: How would I do this as I need the functions in my custom class, ClSprites.

Comment: You could just cast each object in the `List` as you use it, or you could create a new `List<ClSprite>` and move the objects from the other list in a `for` loop. Neither solution seems ideal but I'm afraid there's no cleaner way.