# Unsure how to write method in Java like template in c

Tags: java

I want to implement a function with signature

```
static boolean checkAnyOutOfBoundary(int[] index,ArrayList<ArrayList<T>> list)
```

Where I want to substitute T with other self-created class(DocScore). I tried to substitute T with Object. But when I try to instantiate the list instance, like

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> DocScoreList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();
for (int i = 0; i < index.length; i++)
DocScoreList.add(root.children.get(i).docList);

The type of root.children.get(i).docList is ArrayList<DocScore>
```

I can not add element into DocScoreList. Does anybody know how can I implement this?

Comment: what's the error message? Also, what type is `root.children.get(i).docList`, is an `ArrayList<Object>`?

Comment: `static boolean <T> check...`

Comment: @JanDvorak it could be `public class SomeClass<T>`...

Comment: It wouldn't matter, since the function is static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static <T> boolean checkAnyOutOfBoundary(int[] index,ArrayList<ArrayList<T>> list)
```

Example of calling it:

```
boolean b = checkAnyOutOfBoundary( new int[]{0,1}, new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>());
```

Comment: How can I invoke this function with specific T? Btw, eclipse shows above is not the right way to write an function...

Answer (score 1):

So you are adding an `ArrayList<DocScore>` to a `ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>` but the add method expects an `ArrayList<Object>`.

Can you provide an `ArrayList<DocStore>` where `ArrayList<Object>` is required? No, because [A bag of banana is not a bag of fruit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1794870/18573)

So `DocScoreList` has to be an `ArrayList` of something to which a `ArrayList<DocStore>` can be added. Some examples are:

- `ArrayList<DocStore>` actual type
- `List<DocStore>` because `ArrayList<T>` *is a* `List<T>`
- `ArrayList<? extends Object>` a list of *some unknown type* that (directly or indirectly) extends `Object`. Since `DocStore` meets the criteria `? extends Object` this will work.
- `List<? extends Object>`
- etc. You get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Because even in the case that `Bar` is a subclass of `Foo`, an ArryList is not a superclass of ArrayList.

Change

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> DocScoreList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();
```

to

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<? extends Object>> DocScoreList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<? extends Object>>();
```

Comment: Do you mean I should write ArrayList<ArrayList<DocScore extends Object>> directly in the DocScoreList declaration or extends Object class in the DocScore class definition?